# jni.h file not found - installing node-java module on OS X El Capitan

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, selenium-webdriver, java-native-interface

I am trying to install `node-java` module which allows Node.js to connect to existing `Java` APIs. Here is the command I am using to install this module:

> sudo npm install java -g

Here is the stack trace of the error I am getting:

```
> java@0.7.2 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/java
> node-gyp rebuild

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/java.o
In file included from ../src/java.cpp:1:
../src/java.h:7:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/java.o]         Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit     (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-   gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit    (child_process.js:810:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.6.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/java
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

The interesting thing to note here is that I am able to install the same module locally with **npm install java** command which installs it in:

```
/Users/[$my_username]/node_modules
```

Here is some additional info:

> Node

```
v0.10.33
```

> Java

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

> $JAVA_HOME

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/include
```

> locate jni.h

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers/jni.h
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-migrator/sdk/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers/jni.h
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/include/jni.h
 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/include/jni.h
```

Comment: To my knowledge `sudo` uses a different environment so it probably doesn't have your `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is old but it comes up as the number one search and this is how I was able to resolve this issue when I tried to install node-java using Java 1.8

The **JAVA_HOME** is pointed to the wrong location.

it should be:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

The best way to set this properly is by exporting it:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0`
```

Within Mac systems, I noticed that if you don't include the 0 at the end of the specified versions it will pull the JRE location, not the JDK which is what node-gyp uses.

also, you want to verify that JAVA_HOME is exported properly you can verify this by running the following command in your terminal:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: This was exactly my issue as well. I didn't have the `.0` at the end of the version number, and it worked fine until I updated to macOS Big Sur, and then I started getting this error.