# npm install java fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found #include <jni.h>

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules, node-java

I am trying to install java node package:

```
npm install java
```

And I am getting following error:

```
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/java.o
In file included from ../src/java.cpp:1:
../src/java.h:7:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
     ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I have Java home path in .bash_profile as:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8);
// /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I am on Big Sur Mac. I did check the folder `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin`

and it does have have jni.h file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428191/jni-h-file-not-found-installing-node-java-module-on-os-x-el-capitan